# Get auth scope "../auth/script.storage" verified instead of just listed in my consent screen

Tags: google-apps-script

After some time working out why our gscript plugin didn't work with error "We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED" we discovered that "../auth/script.storage" was listed in our consent screen.

We assume here that this scope is perhaps a new scope that didn't previously exist that are app now requires. We discount the possibility that we accidentally added the scope ourselves, forcing the app to fail when in fact it does not require this scope.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUjY1.png
The attached image is a screenshot of our listed authentication scopes. The green tick, when hovered over says "This API scope is approved and no longer restricted for use."

As you can see, the scope we want does not have the desired green tick.

We then asked for verification, on the assumption that the scopes in the list would be scopes that could be verified on submission.

It is difficult to speculate what other purpose having scopes in the list would serve.

However, our submission came back successful and our green tick for the desired scope was not granted. Our plugin still fails with the same error.

How might we proceed with the submission request and have the auth scope we need be granted to us?

Some more stuff we don't know:
We don't know why email, profile and openid are in the list, why they appear twice and why the 2nd set are removalable and the first set aren't.

Comment: `email`, `openid` and `profile` are all default scopes and the duplicated ones can be removed as they aren't needed. As for the `script.storage` scope, this [appears to be something the application needs for accessing app-specific data](https://i.imgur.com/ZGQuBD4.png). I did notice, however, that it isn't available as a scope to select manually, even with the Apps Script API activated. I suggest you remove the duplicated scopes and attempt to verify again, Otherwise this could be a case of needing to contact G Suite support directly. Can you see if re-verifying works and get back to me here?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks for your reply, its good to know in particular what script.storage does.

What I have discovered is there's a trick here, you can manually paste in the auth scope's you need by finding their web address using the little description at the bottom when adding scopes.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage
(that one throws a 404, but https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.info is present)
And the ui shortens it to ../auth/x

This worked and we were able to submit a verification.

Comment: We have actually got a response back saying our scopes are verified, it just hasn't yet had any effect. The app is still broken with the same error and we don't have the green ticks on the consent screen edit page for script.storage  and documents.currentonly, so sending an email about that.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. For testing purposes could you try and create a new, temporart GCP project with the same scopes and see if that becomes verified? Also, at where in your plugin do you get a point of failure? Is it on build, or on the call of a specific line? If it's the latter could you post the relevant code as a minimal reproducible example?